# clang-format add extra space for negative integer value of throw statement

Tags: c++, clang-format

clang-format add extra space for negative integer value of throw statement, so code `throw -1;` is formatting like `throw - 1;`
How I could fix my .clang_format file to get `throw -1;` after formatting?
clang-format version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)

Parenthesis around value are not allowed for this project

My .clang-format is:

```
---
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands:   true
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: InlineOnly
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:     0
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: All
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Right
RawStringFormats:
  - Delimiter:       pb
    Language:        TextProto
    BasedOnStyle:    google
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    false
SortUsingDeclarations: false
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: Never
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Cpp03
TabWidth:        8
UseTab:          Never
...
```

**update:** clang-format version 7.0.0 (tags/google/stable/2018-01-11) gives same result

Comment: `const int value = -1; throw value;` :) but strange to use `int` for throw instead of custom class.

Comment: Does it change `int a = -1;` as well? I don't see any particular setting for unary operators here.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen no. `return -1;` and `int a = -1;` are formatting well. Problem only with throw statement

Comment: That's peculiar. It could be clang-format bug? Worth checking their backlog for that.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I couldn't find anything like it on [https://bugs.llvm.org](https://bugs.llvm.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__all__&content=format%20throw&no_redirect=1&order=Importance&product=clang-tools-extra&query_format=specific)